# Image is displaying as button on iOS

Tags: ios, html, image, button

I am having an issue with images displaying as buttons (with the title text as the text of the button) in the iPhone 5 browser.  I have tried GIF, PNG and JPG file types.. all with the same effect. It is not happening with all images... but one consistence appear to be

Any advise?

Code example:

```
<a href="/index.php?main_page=checkout_shipping">
<img width="159" height="27" title=" Proceed to Checkout " alt="Proceed to Checkout" src="includes/templates/template_default/buttons/english/button_checkout.jpg">
</a>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Post some code and maybe screenshot.

Comment: Please explain. Images as buttons? Are you using UIButtons and assigning images to them? What does the browser have to do with it?

Comment: Maybe I tagged the question incorrectly... this is occurring on Safari on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the UIWebView is considering your `alt` as the data, so, dispaying a text instead of the image. Verify if your image really exists in that folder or, try removing the `alt` from the `a href` tag o see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Give an ID to  tag and style them with css.

## HTML

```
<a id="checkout" href="/index.php?main_page=checkout_shipping">
    <img width="159" height="27" title=" Proceed to Checkout " alt="Proceed to Checkout" src="includes/templates/template_default/buttons/english/button_checkout.jpg" />
</a>
```

## CSS

```
a#checkout {
    float:right;
    margin:10px;
    width:159px;
    height:27px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
a#checkout img{
    float:right;
    width:159px;
    height:27px;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
}
```